# ssh multiple custon key names

Tags: ssh

I have multiple Raspberries, each with a unique key eg: pi1_id_rsa, pi2_id_rsa and pi3_id_rsa. I want to do `ssh pi1` or `ssh pi2` to shell into a pi.

For this, I have put in `~/.ssh/config`,

```
...

Host pi1
    Hostname pi1@name1.local
    User name1 # This is hostname, maybe it's wrong?
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/pi1_id_rsa

...
```

`sudo ssh pi1@name1.local` works, however it does not use ssh key, instead it asks for a password and the point of keys is to avoid passwords.

Doing `ssh pi1`, gives the error `ssh: Could not resolve hostname pi1@name1.local: Temporary failure in name resolution`. The same address is resolved with password login. The difference here is that ssh should use Hostname in .ssh/config to connect to the pi.

Perhaps, the problem is that everything is on a local network and .ssh/config is not meant to resolve addresses in this way?

Edit: It may not be completely clear, the idea of this is have a good amount of security, the ssh setup should be scalable AND elegant. I looked at a few guides for setting up ssh keys on raspberry and none of them were scalable and/or secure (eg: many guides suggest reusing keys made for git or another pi).

Thanks.

Comment: "I have put in ~/.ssh/config" It is far from clear what you are trying to do. Have you created private/public keys? In general you put both in `~/.ssh` on the host and add public key to client

Comment: @Milliways Apologies. Yes. In IdentityFile you can see path and name of private key. The last line of first paragraph is the aim: "I want to do `ssh pi1` or `ssh pi2` to shell into a pi.". Thanks.

Comment: Again what you want to do is unclear. I have 9 Pi and can `ssh` into any Pi (I currently have open ssh sessions to 4) - they all have the same public key.

Comment: @Milliways I think you are asking "What is the point of this". I have added an edit to the original post at the bottom critiqing existing approaches. For your pleasure (or inspiration), my git and gpg keys are setup like [this](https://markentier.tech/posts/2021/02/github-with-multiple-profiles-gpg-ssh-keys) because I have multiple git accounts on various providers (GitHub, GitLab, Azure DevOps, etc) and require security and convenience in using all of them.

Comment: If there are still some doubts, I want to do `ssh pi1` and shell into pi1. `ssh pi2` should shell into pi2. This must be done securely and the approach must be scalable. I have already done most of the work: ssh finds the correct key to use for the correct pi, but can not connect to the pi.

Comment: You should add the public key to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` to allow the user using `~/.ssh/id_rsa` to sign in without a password. No mucking about except to move the public key round the network.

Comment: @Dougie how will the computer know which private key to use? There is 1 per pi.

Comment: All the additional details you have specified in Comments belongs in your Question. Any question where the OP has multiple comments indicates that the question is lacking.

Comment: You copy the public key from *every* pi or other Linux system that wants to connect. The `authorized_keys` file is then searched when you attempt to connect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with `Hostname pi1@name1.local` the `pi1@name1.local` is not a valid hostname. Remove the `pi1@` part: `Hostname name1.local`.

It looks like the user name is `pi1` based on your `ssh` example.
So, you probably also want `User pi1` in your .ssh/config.

```
Host pi1 name1 name1.local
    HostName name1.local
    User pi1
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/pi1_id_rsa
```

Then you should be able to do `ssh pi1` or `ssh name1` or `ssh name1.local`, they're all equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Your real question (based on Comments) seems to be how to specify a private key.

Your host can have multiple private keys (although why you would want to do this on a private network eludes me).

`ssh -i identity_file`

> Selects a file from which the identity (private key) for public key authentication is read. … Identity files may also be specified on a per-host basis in the configuration file.  It is possible to have multiple -i options (and multiple identities specified in configuration files).

Comment: This would work but we can do better by automating selecting private key and Hostname with the config file. In addition, the config file also gives us other advantages such as specifying rules.